# Full Screen Firefox -- show bar at the bottom?

Tags: firefox, fullscreen

I use firefox in full screen a lot on my netbook and i would like to be able to see the bar on the bottom, because i often hover over links before clicking on them. is it possible  to get it to show in fullscreen?

Answer (score 3):

The [AutoHide extension](http://www.krickelkrackel.de/autohide/) for Firefox lets you customize what is shown in full screen mode. I have been using it for years, and I like it. It has many options, including the ability to show the status bar in full screen mode. It can also show tooltips when you hover over links to show you the destination of the link without taking up space with the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

Or the [status address bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/14933) (experimental) extension will show in the address bar the link that you mouse over. Been using it for a while with no problems. If this is the only thing you need the status bar you could use this and totally disable the bar.

Comment: I use this one too. Problem is: the adress bar also hides in full screen mode. Is there a way to avoide that?

Answer (score 1):

Use the full screen status bar extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/13506