# Firefox - always show the tabs in fullscreen mode

Tags: firefox, taskbar, browser-tabs, fullscreen

Full screen can be more fun if I can always see my **tabs** (by default you can see when you hover your mouse around that area) and my **taskbar**.

I know [how to make taskbar always appear](https://superuser.com/questions/39434/full-screen-firefox-show-bar-at-the-bottom). Any idea how to do this for the "tab-bar"?

Comment: Maximize the window? :)

Comment: no i don't want to see the title bar!

Comment: What would be even more awesome would be to only show the tabs / location bar when they get focused somehow (through keyboard shortcuts). That is basically possible with: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/reviews/add although it also has further side effects.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

1. Type **about:config** on Firefox address
   bar.
2. Search for
   **browser.fullscreen.autohide**
3. Set it to false

There you go.

Comment: Works great and is ridiculously simple. +1

Comment: Perfect with <https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-lessChrome-HD/>, which auto-hides the navigation bar.

Comment: This is awesome. Huge productivity gain for me. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect !! Made my day. A huge productivity gain for me too.

Comment: How simple... Why didn't I just google the solution until today...

Comment: There's some way to show only the tab bar and not the navbar?

Answer (score 1):

[Full Fullscreen](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1568) add-on does exactly that.