# Show tabs in Chrome full screen mode?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, fullscreen

Firefox can do it, can Chrome?

Here's what I'm looking for:

[Firefox - always show the tabs in fullscreen mode](https://superuser.com/questions/43964/firefox-always-show-the-tabs-in-fullscreen-mode)

Comment: It appears to be true that the function you seek isn't supported, but maximizing in Google Chrome is so tight to screen boarders that if you're showing tabs maximized that would seem to be the same effect you're seeking.  Did i miss something in your explanation?

Comment: Sorry, can't find an extension for this... By the way, tip: CTRL+TAB ;-)

Comment: I want tabs but I want to utilize as much screen space as possible on my laptop. Full screen hides the taskbar and nav bar for that extra bit of space.

Comment: Autohiding the taskbar isn't enough?

Comment: I'd prefer not to autohide, but that is an option.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm using Google Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.79) and fullscreen mode still shows the tabs!

You can toggle fullscreen mode using:

- mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

  - or <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>
  - or you can do it manually by going to the menu and choosing `View | Enter Full screen`
- windows: <kbd>F11</kbd>

and you can toggle the bookmarks bar using:

- mac: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
- windows: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>

Which gives you lots more space!

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be the one accepted.
Tested on Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

Comment: what about windows/linux

Comment: updated, hopefully correct, as I'm on mac.

Comment: That solution won't work on Linux, where the only way to go full screen is via F11. The tabs and the omnibox will then be hidden (tested on Chrome 109.0.5414.74).

Comment: This doesn't work anymore - is it just me? Or did Google take away this feature?

Comment: They changed it maybe, so it's now FN+F to toggle to full screen - you can do it manually by going to the menu and choosing "View | Enter Full screen"

Answer (score 28):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

That exits presentation mode and (I think) solves your problem.

Comment: This didn't work in Chrome 26 on OS X 10.8.  Cmd-Shift-F is now bound to "Exit Presentation Mode" (see the "View" menu).  I note that exiting leaves fullscreen as well.  Exiting, then re-entering Fullscreen mode does restore the tabs and address bar as expected.

Comment: No this isnt the answer to the question asked. The question asked for tabs AND fullscreen, which is what i came here to find so i can flip between my chrome windows with the 4 finger swipe motion. Exiting fullscreen takes away that convenience

Comment: View -> Always Show toolbar in full screen.

Comment: Doesn't work in Chrome on Linux.

Comment: Any solution for Chrome linux?

Answer (score 12):

The most recent version is go to "View" and activate

> Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen

It says <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> also works, but that didn't work for my computer.

Answer (score 8):

The extension [Fullscreen address bar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ppmkmdianhgppfjciekeiodmgdppglno?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) does:

> Address bar for fullscreen mode : Use
>   F6 key or move mouse to top
>   screen.
>  Tab list : Use ctrl key
>   and top/down arrows

[image]

Comment: Didn't work immediately on Ubuntu, but works if you restart and open new tabs.

Comment: I've accepted this as the best answer, but I am concerned. Why does the extension need to access "Your data on all websites...browsing history... bookmarks"?

Comment: It only needs them if it intends to display them as choices when one types-in a partial URL. Even if it does not, this may be for "future use".

Comment: Maybe, but there is no way to know. For the record, there is no review on Google's site. Existing on a Google hosted server does not make an extension legit. If you post an extension, it shows up right away. Caveat emptor.

Comment: This extension now has many reviews and appears safe, but I can't get it to work.  On this other hand, the extension Fullscreen Address Bar has only a few reviews but works for me: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fullscreen-address-bar/ppmkmdianhgppfjciekeiodmgdppglno

Comment: doesn't work for me on windows 8 but this shows address bar, though not tabs https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-screen-static-naviga/oihgjjmlcmdjjdpkeccmbnmhgaheokfp

Comment: Down-voting an answer from 2010 ?

Answer (score 3):

I just toggle the bookmarks bar on and off (ctrl-shift-B) when I need a little bit more space, but not so much more that I use fullscreen mode. There's no way to toggle the address bar as well.

Ctrl-tab still works when you're in fullscreen mode, so this is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle tabs upwards and backward also using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Pg Up</kbd> or <kbd>Pg Dn</kbd>.

Comment: good to know when we only want to switch between 2 tabs close together

Answer (score 0):

Relaunch Chrome in Windows 8 mode. Than right click on task bar (shelf) at the bottom, enable auto-hide