# How do I enter a URL in Chrome's full-screen mode?

Tags: google-chrome

It would be really convenient to be able to quickly run a search or check my e-mail without having to escape full-screen mode. Is this possible in Chrome? Is there a key shortcut that would allow me to access the URL bar?

Comment: 11 years late, but if the tabs are already open hotkeys can switch between them. And this [hotkey](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/384179/24640) or a similar one will show the URL bar.

Comment: in mac os press shift + command + F to toggle addressbar in fullscreen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Chrome does not allow that by default. See this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8022).

One option to achieve this would be to install MyAddressBar extension which will let you define a user configured key combination to bring up an address bar.

Comment: Neither MyAddressBar nor the extension recommended below worked for me with Chrome 54 on Win10, and from reading other comments I think they don't work for all Windows users.

Comment: 14 upvotes? Have people given up on this thing?

Comment: @molgar Cannot find your `MyAddressBar` suggestion in the Chrome Web Store : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/MyAddressBar?_category=extensions

Answer (score 13):

Chrome by default doesn't allow any type of UI in full screen mode. That is, without the use of an extension. [[Reference Link]](http://lifehacker.com/5161528/google-chrome-development-builds-get-full+screen-mode)

However, if you using a keyboard with a Windows Key then you can push [Windows Key] + [R]. This will bring up the run box. Type in the address you want and hit enter. If Google Chrome is your default browser then it will bring up a new web page.

As an additional note, to switch between tabs, push [CTRL] + [#]. Replace the # with a real number.

Comment: I believe Winkey+R is the best solution, because using the above mentioned extension, exposes all your personal data on all websites you surf to the "Fullscreen address bar" developer.

Comment: Not sure about your assertion that no UI is allowed in full screen mode.  The fact that the search box doesn't work in full screen is considered a bug that needs to be fixed:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473782

Answer (score 12):

You can use [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) and access address bar with "o"/"O" hotkeys ("open URL"/"open URL in new tab").

Comment: As someone who is used to using the Omnibar via the new tab page, I found this answer to be most helpful, in the spirit of the usability I was looking for. It's very similar to the Ctrl+P in Submlime, Ctrl+T in Visual Studio, Command-space in MacOS. I like it.

Comment: Hmm. I don't understand how to configure Vimium, and pressing the "o" key does nothing.

Comment: @StefanReich extensions do not work on `chrome://newtab` pages, so make sure you're using this on a proper webpage

Answer (score 11):

You could use Ctrl-T to open a new tab, which will show the Google search page.  You could also use Ctrl-H to show your history and search through pages visited previously (Google and your mail page will certainly be on that list).

Comment: Also CTRL-Tab to switch between tabs, CTRL-W to close current tab

Comment: This is actually not an answer. The new tab page with Ctrl-T is the actual problem the OP is asking about, since the Omnibar there does not work.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 ways I can think of

**First way:**

1. `F11` - To get out of full screen mode temporarily
2. `F6` - Shortcut key to URL bar
3. Enter URL and press enter
4. `F11` - Get back to full screen mode

**Second way:**

1. `F12` - To open up inspector
2. `ESC` - Shortcut key to open console within inspector
3. type into console `window.location = 'http://[webpage.com]'`, hit `ENTER`
4. `F12` - To turn off inspector

Comment: Scripting your way to a new page. What a great answer and quicker than one might think.

Answer (score 2):

you can leverage on this extension for tab and url management in full screen mode.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-url-manager/egiemoacchfofdhhlfhkdcacgaopncmi

Comment: I've just installed your extension on Linux, it works fine, congratulations :).
Now, it does not use the default search engine I've defined in the browser.
It also lacks other search engines such as duckduckgo, qwant, etc... Can you please add them ?
Do you have a github or gitlab (or other) url for your project ?

Answer (score 1):

It is [possible](https://superuser.com/a/1417343/1083563) to view that toolbar if fullscreen mode is on.

> View > Always Show Toolbar in Full Screen

- Hotkey: <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Than quick jump to address bar:
  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd>*
- Than if you want to search just type:
  <kbd>?</kbd>

*[Official reference](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179)*

** If not works visit: [this](https://superuser.com/q/1400915/1083563) or [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/333371)*

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Chrome, Microsoft Edge allows you to go full screen and still be able to access web page tabs by hovering near the top of the screen.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).