# what does "ctrl + f6" do in chrome?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, laptop, shortcuts

of course I checked the google support page first

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179

and it is specified as "Skip to web contents"
what does this exactly do while browsing? Nothing seemed to happen when I pressed that key.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1403752/603073

Answer (score 1):

It will move the cursor on the webpage and scroll to markers in the document that mark the start of text blocks. (skipping menus at the top and other images)

For this to work, the website must have these markers in them, which is the same as what screen readers use. Without, it should still make the webpage get focus so you can move around with the arrow key.

Comment: can you give me an example url to test out? I've tested several websites for minutes, and none of them does a darn thing.

Comment: I don't know of any site that supports this. Tried a few that I thought would work, but they don't. Don't have time to actively look for one.